# Let a group G act on a set $X$, and suppose that $x,y \in X$ lie in the same orbit. Prove that $G_y=g^{-1}G_xg$ for some $g \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let a group G act on a set $X$, and suppose that $x,y \in X$ lie in the same orbit. Prove that $G_y=g^{-1}G_xg$ for some $g \in G$

Ok, lets assume $G$ acts on $X$,where $x,y \in X, g \in G$ and $y=gx$. Let $k \in G_y$. Then, $ky=y$ and

$$(g^{-1}kg)x=(g^{-1}k)(gx)=(g^{-1}k)y=g^{-1}(ky)=g^{-1}y=g^{-1}(gx)=(g^{-1}g)x=x$$

Therefore, $g^{-1}G_yg \subseteq G_x$

Does this logic seem sound? Would I be able to use a similar method to prove the other inclusion?

Comment: I think you showed $\;g^{-1}G_yg\subset G_x\;$ and not what you wrote in the last line (not that it matters, of course... *why?* ). Also, how did that $\;a\;$ at the end of the line before the last one (of calculations) come into being? I think you meant $\;x\;$ there...

Comment: @Timbuc, yes typos

Comment: Yes, you would be able to do so (just use $h = g^{-1}$ as the element of $G$ you need, so that $x = hy$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your logic is sound. And, using @David Wheeler's suggestion, here is a slightly more polished answer. For $x,y$ in the same orbit, we have $g(x)=y$ and we want to show that $$gG_xg^{-1}=G_y$$
If $h\in G_x$, then
$$\begin{aligned} ghg^{-1}(y)&=ghg^{-1}(g(x)) \\&= gh(x) \\&=g(x) \\&=y \end{aligned}$$
Therefore, $gG_xg^{-1}\subseteq G_y$. Reversing the roles of $x$ and $y$ the same argument provides $gG_yg^{-1}\subseteq G_x$; in other words, $G_y \subseteq gG_xg^{-1}$, completing the proof.

Comment: How is $gG_yg^{-1} \subset G_x$ equivalent to $G_y \subset gG_xg^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Sorry if I answer this much later. Just to make sure others understand: There was a little mistake on Jacopo's answer. For the conversely contention, first, it's required to show that $g^{-1} G_y g \subseteq G_x$ just as the above way. Now, let's show that $G_y \subseteq g G_x g^{-1}$. Let $h \in G_y$, then $g^{-1} h g \in G_x$. Thus,  $g(g^{-1} h g)g^{-1} = h \in gG_x g^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a direct approach.**

$(G, *)$ is a group acting on a set $X$ by $\circ$. Let $x, y \in X$ be in the same orbit. Then, $y = g \circ x$ for some $g \in G.$

Recall that the stabilizers of $x, y$ are given by
\begin{equation*}
G_x = \{g_x \in G ~: g_x \circ x = x\}  ~~\text{ and }~~ G_y = \{g_y \in G ~: g_y \circ y = y\}. 
\end{equation*}

Choose two stabilizers of $x,y: ~g_x \in G_x, ~g_y \in G_y.$ Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{(g_y * g)} \circ x &=   \\
&= g_y \circ (g \circ x)  \\
&= g_y \circ y  \\
&=y \\
&= g \circ x \\
&= g \circ (g_x \circ x) \\
&= \mathbf{(g * g_x)} \circ x.\\
\end{align*}
$\circ ~\text{ Injective } \implies \mathbf{g_y * g = g * g_x} \implies g_y = g * g_x * g^{-1}.$ The choice of $x, y$ is arbitrary, hence the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in O(y)$, then $\exists\tilde g\in G$ such that $x=\tilde gy$. Therefore, by group action properties:
\begin{alignat}{1}
G_y&=\{g\in G\mid gy=y\} \\
&=\{g\in G\mid g(\tilde g^{-1}x)=\tilde g^{-1}x\} \\
&=\{g\in G\mid (\tilde gg\tilde g^{-1})x=x\} \\
&\stackrel{(g':=\tilde gg\tilde g^{-1})}{=}\{\tilde g^{-1}g'\tilde g\in G\mid g'x=x\} \\
&=\tilde g^{-1}\{g'\in G\mid g'x=x\}\tilde g \\
&=\tilde g^{-1}G_x\tilde g \\
\end{alignat}